# Get object property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I have an object that contains an array of objects from which I need to get a value of their properties.

As an example this is what I need to get:

```
Stronghold.bins.models[0].attributes.entity.title
```

Which returns "Stronghold Title 1"

```
function grabItemName(){
   var itemName=$(Stronghold.bins).each(function(){
      return this.models[0].attributes.entity.title == title;
      console.log(itemName);
   })
};
```

(if there is a better way for me to ask this question please let me know)

I apologize if this was poorly asked!

The current issue is that it does not understand the array value '[0]' and cannot read it as it is undefined. What do I need to do to grab the 'title' value of all items in the array?

Comment: I don't think you even asked a question...

Comment: Try using `each` the correct way for object literals and arrays: `$.each(Stronghold.bins).each(function () { });`

Comment: What do you get if you put console.log(this) above the return statement?

Comment: I think you have to understand what `.each` is actually doing: http://api.jquery.com/each/. And since you are not working with DOM elements, you might better use `$.each`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/. And in order to properly help you, you have to explain what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Where is the `title` variable coming from? Why are you performing an equality comparison? Why are you returning the result of that comparison? Why are you storing the result of the `.each()`? Describe clearly what you ultimately need. Your attempt at a solution looks like random syntax thrown together.

Comment: @thesystem Another good question is "Why are you using `console.log` **after** a `return`?"

Comment: @Ian: Indeed. Maybe to make sure the `return` statement is still working? :P

Comment: @thesystem Ahh I forgot about that. You can never be too sure with those pesky `return` trickster statements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to do to grab the 'title' value of all items in the array?

That's what [`.map` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) is for. It lets you map each value in an array to another value.

In the following I assume you want to iterate over each `Stronghold.bins.models`, because iterating over `Stronghold.bins` does not make sense with the provided information:

```
var titles = $.map(Stronghold.bins.models, function(obj) {
    return obj.attributes.entity.title;
});
// `titles` is now an array containing `.attributes.entity.title;` of
// each object.
```

> The current issue is that it does not understand the array value '[0]' and cannot read it as it is undefined.

Well, that won't happend anymore ;) In your example you where iterating over the properties of the `Stronghold.bins` object. One of these properties is `models` itself (!) and I doubt that any other property value has a `models` property.

Comment: I think perhaps OP wants to dynamically get the value of an object property using a function. The example given is `Stronghold.bins.models[0].attributes.entity.title`, so I think OP is after a simple `return Stronghold.bins.models[0].attributes.entity[title]`, where `title` is the function parameter. Could be wrong though. Can't tell from the question.

Comment: ...or maybe `bins` is indeed a collection, and `.map()` is needed as well. Who knows.

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks for the professional and instructional response! I apologize to everyone else for the confusion. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: @thesystem: I should have had a closer look at the code. I actually think the OP wants to iterate over `Stronghold.bins.models`.

Comment: @FelixKling: That could be. There's that statement about not understanding `[0]`. Could be that there's a nested Array as well. It's too hard to reverse engineer a non-functioning solution.

Comment: Also, @FelixKling, that is correct. Thank you for the final edit there!

Answer (score -1):

Try using the other version of the each function:

```
$.each(Stronghold.bins, function () {

});
```

The version you are using is for looping through an element on the page, e.g `$('body div p').each(function() {})`, which isn't what you want in this instance: You want to loop over the values contained in `Stronghold.bins`.

Comment: They are quite equivalent, only one returns the array wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: Maybe so, but as there is absolutely no reason to wrap the array in a jQuery object when it's nothing to do with the DOM.

Comment: @ChrisC Bergi's point is that they do the same thing...except that `$(items).each()` actually returns a jQuery object...you know, like for chaining? Otherwise, they accomplish/do the same thing internally (inside the callback). It works fine with the OP's code: http://jsfiddle.net/WrERZ/

Comment: @ChrisC: Of course it's not necessary, yet changing it will not help the OP to solve his problem.